# Increase font size of color scale in image.plot function

Tags: r, plot, scale

I want to increase the font size of my spatial plot especially the colorbar. I am using image.plot() function, but I don't know how to increase the size since it is not a regular plot.
This is my script :

```
image.plot(lon,lat,tas_slice,
col=colorscale,breaks=brks,lab.breaks=brks,
xaxt="n", yaxt="n", ann=FALSE,horizontal=T,cex=4)
map(database="world", add=TRUE)
axis(side=1, at=seq(-10,40,10), labels=lon_labels,las=1)
axis(side=2, at=seq(40,70,10), labels=lat_labels,las=1)
  # we add longitudes and latitudes to the map
  # abline(h=seq(-80,80,10), v=seq(-180,177.5,10), lty=2)
  title(main=paste(SEA[fileno],proj,param,model,time_per[fileno],
                   sep=" "),
        line=2,cex.lab=3, cex.axis=3, cex.main=3, cex.sub=3)
  mtext("[°C]", side=1, line=3.5,cex=1.5)
```

And this scale that i want to increase its font size because it is too small and not visible for publication. I really appreciate if anyone can help me.
Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: In `?image.plot`, there is this: "The text is too small! This always seems to happen as one is rushing to finish a talk and the figures have tiny default axis labels. Try just calling the function fields.style before plotting. List out this function to see what is changed, however, all text is increased by 20% in size." Does running `fields.style()` before plotting help?

Comment: Unfortunately, no it doesnt work